# How to get all parent Id from a child Id in nested JSON with children

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

```js
function loadKendoTreeView() 
{
  if ($("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView") != null) 
  {                     $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").destroy();
  $("#treeview").empty(); 
  }

var jsonData = [{ "Id": "239297d8-5993-42c0-a6ca-38dac2d8bf9f", "Name": "SampleSite1", "ChildAssets": [{ "Id": "9ee67548-f511-4d0e-8690-b7e1951ac27f", "Name": "Plant0", "ChildAssets": [{ "Id": "8678ba42-2d7a-4956-a915-415a457c0196", "Name": "Area0", "ChildAssets": [{ "Id": "36d02c55-e908-44a5-ba33-07e0125e9eed", "Name": "Unit0", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "ed1c13ff-d5e5-4fe6-8ce0-bfd5e76b814c", "Name": "Unit1", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "0d892c0e-01fd-4ea3-a6ab-b8550bc87a5d", "Name": "Unit2", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "a12d1db9-9b6e-441c-bacc-2d9692b3afb3", "Name": "Unit3", "ChildAssets": [] }] }, { "Id": "049c376a-1ef5-45ee-be05-b607cc668fbd", "Name": "Area1", "ChildAssets": [{ "Id": "edb6404f-8370-401a-bd86-b461f5022d8f", "Name": "Unit0", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "199afe72-9dce-4cd3-b049-cb3d4be0a956", "Name": "Unit1", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "8a1b846e-5421-475e-9cc7-cda150cd1ced", "Name": "Unit2", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "795271e8-be9a-43e9-b751-910dce7ecc36", "Name": "Unit3", "ChildAssets": [] }] }] }, { "Id": "a8e55efc-9cc6-40ae-bf40-77d84b28d885", "Name": "Plant1", "ChildAssets": [{ "Id": "87662856-0960-4c4c-991d-705dc7ae67b7", "Name": "Area0", "ChildAssets": [{ "Id": "37da98ed-5deb-4ee4-8c15-59e8c0a280c0", "Name": "Unit0", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "2fedd165-a1fa-43e8-9f24-b511a9d86a75", "Name": "Unit1", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "6c245afa-9f81-487b-aba4-246cae104ece", "Name": "Unit2", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "ff1dcb66-8cb6-455c-bcb2-386bfdeb90b2", "Name": "Unit3", "ChildAssets": [] }] }, { "Id": "15449560-2ae0-43e5-b442-a9a9a6443bbd", "Name": "Area1", "ChildAssets": [{ "Id": "72cf17bc-fa86-4147-bb4a-0db243e1c090", "Name": "Unit0", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "793bac08-ab06-4fa7-9fe9-36efebc5f92f", "Name": "Unit1", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "159f1b72-3133-4bce-898e-08c515207e51", "Name": "Unit2", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "deb3b828-8f2b-41b9-a2de-41e9e9c5bc31", "Name": "Unit3", "ChildAssets": [] }] }] }, { "Id": "eb5bc83f-7c10-4427-a07f-602545855efd", "Name": "Plant2", "ChildAssets": [{ "Id": "b41ba788-f29b-4cda-898b-0794d7017607", "Name": "Area0", "ChildAssets": [{ "Id": "a63e253e-7712-477b-820f-368bd87c26bd", "Name": "Unit0", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "6fe78e83-ffcf-4326-96d9-a56f6df7b3d5", "Name": "Unit1", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "23f87c08-3d35-447e-ac99-4addb6e97909", "Name": "Unit2", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "c9eed14d-6447-4b45-89d6-1f9bbb3c2586", "Name": "Unit3", "ChildAssets": [] }] }, { "Id": "ec36edcf-b7b1-4baa-ab15-43cd04dd0e4f", "Name": "Area1", "ChildAssets": [{ "Id": "76fdf6ef-b657-4f00-8632-48451f21d40a", "Name": "Unit0", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "a392264a-8775-4126-82b1-a1bf939c58c3", "Name": "Unit1", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "13c55334-1420-4431-93a6-805c1dba01d5", "Name": "Unit2", "ChildAssets": [] }, { "Id": "1672db36-dccf-452b-b091-9cf9c17a40c1", "Name": "Unit3", "ChildAssets": [] }] }] }] }];
                    hierarchicalDataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                        data: jsonData,
                         schema: {
                             model: {
                                 id: "Id",
                                 hasChildren: function (e) {
                                     if (e && e.ChildAssets && e.ChildAssets.length > 0) {
                                         return true;
                                     } else {
                                         return false;
                                     }
                                 },
                                 children: "ChildAssets"
                             }
                         }
                     });

                   
                   
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                  loadOnDemand: true,
                  dataSource: hierarchicalDataSource,
                  dataTextField: "Name",
                  select: function (e) {
                  var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.node);
                  selectedNode = dataItem.Id;
                         },
                     });

                     var kendoTreeInstance = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
                     var selectedNode = {
                         "Id": "23f87c08-3d35-447e-ac99-4addb6e97909",
                         "Name": "Unit2",
                         "ChildAssets": []
                     };

addSlectionAndExpandTreeViewNodeSelected(kendoTreeInstance, selectedNode);
                 }

                function addSlectionAndExpandTreeViewNodeSelected(kendoTreeInstance, selectedNode) {
                  var parentIdArray = ["239297d8-5993-42c0-a6ca-38dac2d8bf9f", "eb5bc83f-7c10-4427-a07f-602545855efd", "b41ba788-f29b-4cda-898b-0794d7017607"];  
                          kendoTreeInstance.expandPath(parentIdArray); //Id's to be expanded as been hard coded, Need to get only parent Ids in the hierarchy of selected node Id


                    var dataItem = kendoTreeInstance.dataSource.get(selectedNode.Id);
                     if (dataItem) {
                         var dataElement = kendoTreeInstance.findByUid(dataItem.uid);                         kendoTreeInstance.select(dataElement);
                     }
                 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/remote-data-binding">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>
        <div id="example">
            <div class="demo-section k-content">
                <button type="button" onclick=loadKendoTreeView()>Load Kendo treeview</button>

                <div id="treeview"></div>
            </div>
                    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Need help in creating an algorithm.
I have a nested json variable with childrens ([JSON](https://api.myjson.com/bins/172qdr)). This json can have nth children, Given an Id from the nested json, I need an array of all Parent Id's which comes in the hierarchy of the selected Id.
Json sample : https://api.myjson.com/bins/172qdr
I need the array of Ids to expand kendo tree hierarchy till selected nth child.

I have hard coded array of Id's in parentIdArray variable to expand tree with those Id's.

Ex. 1. If Unit2 is selected under Area0->Plant2->SampleSite1. Then Array should contain these parent Ids.

Ex. 2. If Area1 is selected under Plant1->SampleSite1. Then Array should contain these parent Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you meen something like this?

```
const findParents = (arr, id) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].Id === id){
      return [];
    }else if(arr[i].ChildAssets && arr[i].ChildAssets.length){

      let t = findParents(arr[i].ChildAssets, id);

      if(t !== false){
        t.push(arr[i].Name);

        return t;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Enter the id and it will return path to it. If there is no such id it returns false.

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/erdJpB)

Comment: Thank you Krill for the solution. It helped me a lot.